# How can I show a problem is in the intersection of np and co-np using duality and Farkas-lemma?

Tags: np, co-np, duality

Currently, I have a hard time to find out the solution to this problem:

Given a matrix $A \in Z^{m \times n}$, $b \in Z^m$, $c \in R^n$ and $\lambda \in  R$. Is there $x \in R^n$ with $Ax \leq b$ and $c^Tx \geq \lambda$?
I was able to show that the given problem is $NP$, but now I have to show it is in $NP \cap co-NP$ by using strong duality and Farkas lemma. I thought it would be enough to show, that given a no certificate $x$, I can calculate $c^Tx$ and compare it with $\lambda$ in polynomial time.

Edit:
We can assume, that all extreme points have polynomial size.

Comment: What is a no certificate in your case? A yes certificate is a vector $x$ such that $Ax \leq b$ and $c^T x \geq \lambda$, but a no certificate should rule out the existence of all such vectors $x$. Also, in the yes case you need to show that $x$ has polynomial size.

Comment: I think a no certificate should be an extreme point $x$, such that $c^Tx$ is maximized and $c^Tx \leq \lambda$.

Comment: How do you check that $c^t x$ is maximized at the given point? You need a certificate for that.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I should take a different approach. I can consider the dual program and ask if there is any $y$ with $b^Ty < \lambda$. A certificate for this can be obtained by a non-deterministic TM and can be checked in polynomial time. A yes certificate would be a no certificate for the primal program. But how does it connect to the primal program beeing in co-np?

Comment: For the problem to be in both NP and coNP, you need certificates for both the yes case and the no case.

Comment: Thank you. I see that I had a misunderstanding about co-np. Since you did not object my definition for the no certificate, may I assume that it is correct?

Comment: You should get the no certificate from strong duality. If that's what you did, it's probably correct.